# 64bit vs 32bit processor execution equivalence

Tags: clock-speed, processing

I'm not sure if I am in the good site but here's my question :

I was questionning myself, what would be comparable(execution speed)  between a 32bit and 64bit processor.  Like what would be the clockrate of a 32bit processor to be as the same speed as a 64bit processor.

Ps : English is not my first language.

Wood

Comment: Dependent on *far* too many factors...

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit is the width of the data bus path. Calculating 1+1=2 is the same speed on both machines. For values greater than 2^32-1 the 32-bit machine requires two cycles versus 1 cycle on 64-bit. However, bigger speed difference comes from memory management, L1 & L2 cache memory, etc.

Comment: @Wood You don't need to "sign" your posts; your user info is always shown with them.

Comment: @JYelton Thanks buddy I will know for the next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about the x86 and x64 instruction sets, there's not a whole lot of difference as the x64 set is backwards compatible with x86, meaning that a 32-bit operating system will easily run on 64-bit hardware.  However, being designed around 32 bits, it will only be able to access 2^32 bytes = 4GB of RAM, even though there might be more installed.  In that comparison, the clock rates are almost identical because of the compatibility.

In pretty much every other case, and even the one above to some extent, you simply can't compare clock rates because the instruction sets are so different.  One may have a super-duper instruction that takes one clock cycle to do a specific task that occurs often in the job that it was designed for, while another may require many instructions to do the same thing.  For that specific job, the first one will perform better with less clock than the second will with more.

This is especially true in embedded software.  Unlike PC's, which have pretty much all standardized now on the x86 or x64 instruction set, every manufacturer of embedded devices has their own incompatible instruction set, which makes it difficult to measure relative performance levels that are less than an order of magnitude or so.

---

Of course, all of this assumes that the instruction rate is the limiting factor.  In most embedded designs, it is, if anything.  In PC's though, the issue is usually memory.  The CPU spends most of its time waiting for the relatively slow RAM or hard drive to get around to returning the data that it needs.  This is why you want a big cache, lots of RAM, and a fast connection in between.

Answer (score 0):

*Unless* the code is handling values bigger than 2^32, there is unlikely to be any measurable difference for a similar Instruction Set Architecture (ISA), with similar cache and memory interface.

However 32bit processors usually have a smaller cache than a 64bit processor, just because of the generation of technology, or the design goals of the products. So the differences are  more about the implementation than the inherent advantages of 32bits over 64bits.

Where a difference may easily be measured is heavy double precision floating point arithmetic, which are 64bit values. The difference can come from both the CPU to memory accesses and the floating point processing unit (FPU) implementation. It is plausible that the clock speed difference between 32bit and 64bit might be closer to 2x. However, even here a bigger difference in performance is likely to be the cache size, memory bus speed, and the implementation of the FPU, than 32bit vs 64bit.

The other main difference is the inability of a 32bit processor to fit as much data into RAM (typically program code size is *much* less than the 4GB).

An 'ordinary' 32bit processor can only directly access a 32 bit address space, 4GB. A 64bit processor has a theoretical address space of \$2^{64}, or 18\cdot10^{18}\$, i.e. 18 exabytes. This isn't usually implemented. However, it is feasible to have more than an order of magnitude more memory on a 64bit processor.

Estimating the impact of fitting all data into memory vs reading from external storage is very difficult. It might be a factor of more than a million, or very small. You'd need to do some benchmarks to find out. Further, by understanding the access patterns to the data, it might be feasible to reduce the differences, even for quite large data sets, to less than 2x.